# How to insert value from form using CodeIgniter and AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, database, codeigniter, base-url

what i was trying to do is to insert value from the form in view to the database using AngularJS with CodeIgniter . 
and i will show my code step by step.

here is my form (view) :

```
<div class=containter ng-controller="create">
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="submitform()"> 

                <div class="form-group" id="nameform"><br>
                    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Full Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.firstname" autofocus>
                        <span class="help-block">Last Name, First Name, eg.: Smith, Harry</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Skype</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Skype" class="form-control" ng-model="user.skype">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Service</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Name your service" class="form-control" ng-model="user.service">
                    </div>
                </div>                   

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Describe your service</label>                                                             
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Please describe your servic you can offer for students in view lines here" ng-model="user.describe" id="comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Country code , Number , ++371 28949227" class="form-control" ng-model="user.number">
                    </div>                                                                                                                                  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Country</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select id="country" class="form-control" ng-model="user.country">


 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block creatbutton">Create new service</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and the AngularJS code is the flowing :

```
var angularFormApp = angular.module('create',[]);

angularFormApp.controller('create',['$scope','$http',
function Formcontroller($scope,$http)
{
     $scope.user = {};
$scope.submitform=function()
{
       $http({
        method:'post',
        url:'<?php echo base_url('Pages/add');?>',
        data : $scope.user, //forms user object
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
    })
};
}]);
```

and my model :

```
class Ektreemodel extends CI_Model
{
public function insert_form($request)
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    $insertStatus=$this->db->insert('final',array(
        'fullname'=>$request['fullname'],
        'email'=>$request['email'],
        'country'=>$request['fromwhere'],
        'service'=>$request['servicetitle'],
        'describe'=>$request['servicedesc'],
        'number'=>$request['phone'],
        'skype'=>$request['skype'],
        'skype'=>$request['gender']
        ));
    return $insertStatus;
 }
}
?>
```

and my controller :

```
   public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('ektreemodel');
        }
        public function add()
        {
            $request= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
            $data=$this->ektreemodel->insert_form($request);

        }
```

Note : i made all the configuration for the database its correct . 
the thing is when i insert value in the from filed is not showing any result . 
i guess its some problem with this line `<?php base_URL('Traget') ?>`. 
but i am not sure . 
please could any one look at the code and tell me what's wrong why i am not getting any result in the database . that i create in the table . "final"

Answer (score 0):

Add hack into file /system/core/Input.php  line 337

```
public function input_new($index= NULL, $xss_clean = NULL){

    $array = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $array=json_decode($array,true);

    return $this->_fetch_from_array($array, $index, $xss_clean);

}
```

use

```
$value = $this->input->input_new("value");
$array = $this->input->input_new(),
```

Comment: i add it the two lines you wrote like this but still no result :

Comment: public function input_stream($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL)
 {
  
  if ( ! is_array($this->_input_stream))
  {
   // $this->raw_input_stream will trigger __get().
   $value = $this->input->input_new("value");
             $array = $this->input->input_new();
   parse_str($this->raw_input_stream, $this->_input_stream);
   is_array($this->_input_stream) OR $this->_input_stream = array();
  }

  return $this->_fetch_from_array($this->_input_stream, $index, $xss_clean);
 }